# Cross domain XMLHTTPRequest error

Tags: xml, ajax, web-services, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I'm trying to load XML data via the jQuery get method. The XML feed is located at the following URL:
http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=routeList&a=mbta

When I run the following code in the browser, I get an error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=routeList&a=mbta.
>   Origin http://173.203.89.156 is not
>   allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title>Bus Map</title>
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.3966499, -71.12188);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        $.get('http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=routeList&a=mbta', function(stops) {
            alert(stops[0]);                                                                                                    
        })
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this domain categorically blocking all cross-domain XMLHTTPRequests, or is there away to bypass this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the browser blocks cross domain xhrs.  There is something called the [Same-Origin-Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you need to follow for xhrs, or you need to use an alternative, like server side proxying or jsonp if it is provided by the application.

Comment: So every time I make an XHR the request and the referer domains and ports must be the same? Is that a security feature?

Comment: @adam, yes, among other things like protocol

Comment: I've used plenty of web services before. What makes this one different?

Comment: @adam, were the services on the same domain that served up the javascript?

Comment: Well the example that comes to mind is Twitter. They have an API that allows you to make cross domain requests, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @adam yes they have an api.  were you accessing it from javascript or from a server, or using something like wget or curl?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get around the same-domain issue (like many APIs do), look into JSONP. I'm not that familiar with jQuery, but it appears to make JSONP calls with [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) if the URL has a callback parameter.

Comment: This works, as long as I append the callback=? parameter to the query string. However, the application throws an error: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <'. Is this because the application is expecting json and getting XML instead?

Comment: Thanks, this is useful info anyway. +1